# xpath for immediate preceding sibling

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

**XML**

```
<root>
  <p>nodea text 1</p>
  <p>nodea text 2</p>
  <nodea>
  </nodea>
  <p>nodeb text 1</p>
  <p>nodeb text 2</p>
  <nodeb>
  </nodeb>
</root>
```

I want to get the first preceding sibling p tag of nodea or nodeb if there is one. For example for the above xml the preceding siblings for respective node are

**nodea** preceding siblings

```
<p>nodea text 1</p>
<p>nodea text 2</p>
```

**nodeb** preceding siblings

```
<p>nodeb text 1</p>
<p>nodeb text 2</p>
```

i have tried the below xpath but it gives me the preceding p tag of nodea instead of nodeb.

```
nodeb = xml.find('nodeb')
nodeb.xpath('preceding-sibling::p[not(preceding-sibling::nodea)][1]')
```

If there is no preceding p tag before the node then it should return empty list. For example for the below xml there are no preceding sibling p tags for nodeb.

```
<root>
  <p>nodea text 1</p> 
  <nodea>
  </nodea>
  <nodeb>
  </nodeb>
</root>
```

It would be nice if someone can also explain why my xpath is not working and what should i keep in mind when writing xpath?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can select `preceding-sibling::*[1][self::p]` to select the preceding sibling element if it is a `p` element.

As for your attempt, I think if you select the `nodeb` element, you then want to select `preceding-sibling::p[preceding-sibling::nodea][1]` as you want to look at the sibling `p`s that are between the `nodeb` and the `nodea` element. Your condition `preceding-sibling::p[not(preceding-sibling::nodea)][1]` indeed selects `p` siblings that don't have a preceding `nodea` sibling and these are the first two `p` elements in document order.

Comment: Its working. Can you please add a little bit of explanation what is wrong with my xpath.

Comment: @MA1, I have added some explanation on your attempt.